# How much of a square is covered by $r$ sub-squares, expectation of the function $2^{-x}$ of that

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let natural numbers $n$ and $k\leq n$ be given. We consider the square made of $n\times n$ tiles. It has $M=(n-k+1)^2$ sub squares of dimensions $k\times k$. We pick $r$ out of these sub squares and ask how many tiles does their union cover. For the ease of speaking, let's say we pick the subsquares at random (uniformly from all ${{M}\choose{r}}$ possible subsets of size $r$). Let's denote as $U$ the random variable counting the size of the union.

In the example picture below $n=6$, $k=3$, $r=4$ and $U=25$.

[image: an example of 4 3x3-subsquares covering 25 tiles of the 6x6-square]

I have managed to calculate $\mathbb{E}[U]$ in the following fashion.

> Let's first count how many sub squares cover each tile. In the corners it is $1$, then grows linearly on the borders up to $k$. And towards the center it grows linearly up to $k^2$. Call this matrix $A$. The following picture for $n=8, k=3$ illustrates this.
> $$ A = 
> \left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> 2 & 4 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
> 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 3 \\
> 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 3 \\
> 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 3 \\
> 3 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 3 \\
> 2 & 4 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
> 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1
> \end{array}\right)
> $$
> Now, since expectation is linear, we can calculate
> $$\mathbb{E}[U] = \sum_{i,j} \mathbb{P}(\text{tile at }(i,j) \text{ gets covered})
> = \sum_{i,j} (1 - \mathbb{P}(\text{none of the chosen tiles cover } (i,j) )) \\
> = \sum_{i,j} \left(1 - \frac{{M-a_{ij}}\choose{r}}{{M}\choose{r}} \right)
> $$
> where $a_{ij}$ is the entry in the matrix $A$. Many terms in the matrix $A$ are same, so we can further improve the efficiency of the calculation.

### The question

So, to the point. What I want to calculate is the expectation of $2^{-U}$.

The distribution of $U$ seems to have some irregularities although for middle $r$'s it seems normalish (because of central limit theorem, I suspect). I have calculated it for $n=6, k=3$ here: [Desmos-applet](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wxgnbavs2b) (Change the variable $a$ to $y_{r}$ to view different values of $r$). You can also find the brute-force SageMath-code I used in there in the code-folder.

**Is there an efficient way to calculate the distribution of $U$ or just $\mathbb{E}[2^{-U}]$ in some other way?**